# Change terminal or terminator profile via keybinding or echo command

Tags: command-line, user-profile, terminator

How can I change profile for terminator or terminal without touching the mouse?

- in terminal alt-t will allow me to get to menu to change profile
- echo -en "\033]0;$*\a"   will allow me to set title from terminal

I'd like to have aliases called "red", "green" etc that allow me to easily change terminal profile so I can more easily distinguish between the many terminals on which I'm doing work.

Does anyone know how to change profile via an echo or keybinding.  It doesn't look like it is supported.

Thanks